# How to populate gridview on button_click after searching from access database?

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a form in c#.net . I want to populate the `gridview` only on button click with entries meeting search criteria.

I have tried but on searching ID it works but on searching FirstName it gives error plz check SQL also.

Code behind:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            try
            {
                string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=L:/New project/Project/Project/Data.accdb";

                string sql = "SELECT * FROM AddressBook WHERE FirstName='" + textBox1.Text.ToString();
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                connection.Open();
                dataadapter.Fill(ds, "AddressBook");
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;

                dataGridView1.DataMember = "AddressBook";
            }
            catch (System.Exception err)
            {
                this.label27.Visible = true;
                this.label27.Text = err.Message.ToString();
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot databind();

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataBind();



"SELECT * FROM AddressBook WHERE FirstName Like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
```

but remember this sql query is vulnerable to SQL injections so make sure after all works to filter out bad characters

Your error was produced because you did not close your query
`FirstName='" + textBox1.Text.ToString();` should be `FirstName='" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "'";` but like that you must type exactly the right name

with using "like" you can get more results

```
FirstName Like '%" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "%'";
```

And `ToString()` is not needed since the Text Property is already a string

Comment: `Databind()` is used in webform, I guess this question is on Winforms, Where `Databind()` is not required.

Comment: Search works ....Thanks Johnn Blade :)  but databind() is not working there it is saying "You are missing using directive or assembly reference

Comment: change the line dataGridView1.DataBind(); to // dataGridView1.DataBind();